# Check answer and get Button Id in Quiz app Android

Tags: android

I'm working on the part of checking the answer once one of four buttons was clicked by user. I'm achieving this by setting Tag on each button and then using `getTag()` in `onClickListener` created to check whether the clicked View's value is equal to corresponding correct answer stored in SQLite db.

The problem is that I can't now get out from this `onClickListener`, 
I want to have a separate method `checkAnswer()` where would be all the logic for the case that answer was true (currently I've put some of it inside `onClickListener`).How can I identify which exactly Button was pressed?

```
    View.OnClickListener answerChecker = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (view.getTag() != null && view.getTag().equals(mCorrectAnswer)) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorButtonCorrectAns));
                mDetailedAnswerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mRatingBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mNextButton.setEnabled(true);
                mScore++;
                mScoreTextView.setText("Score: " + mScore);


            } else {
               view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorButtonWrongAns));

                }
        }
    };
    mChoice1.setOnClickListener(answerChecker);
    mChoice2.setOnClickListener(answerChecker);
    mChoice3.setOnClickListener(answerChecker);
    mChoice4.setOnClickListener(answerChecker);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally when I'm dealing with many components that have onclick events I will try to combine everything into one function.

for instance if you have an activity/fragment you could use the following code

```
    public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{

     @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getContentView());

        Button btn1 = findviewbyid(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 = findviewbyid(R.id.btn2);
        Button btn3 = findviewbyid(R.id.btn3);
        Button btn4 = findviewbyid(R.id.btn4);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btn1:
                //will trigger when you press on first btn
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
//will trigger when you press on the second btn
                break;
            case R.id.btn3:
                //will trigger when you press on the third btn
                break;
            case R.id.btn4:
                //will trigger when you press on the fourth btn
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The event function of every button assigned by this line

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

When pressed it will triggered the "global" (View.onClickListener method in the activity) and you could differentiate the buttons by using the view.getId() functionality